# in react, how to subscribe to document mousemove?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

this is my code in vanilla JavaScript

```js
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
   console.log(e.pageX) //just a placeholder code
})
```

my question is: how to replicate this code in react (I use react hooks)? I want to subscribe to the event document wide and have in available to a specific component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use useEffect for subscribe. In the return function you should add the cleanup function to release the resources.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const mouseListener = (e) => {
       console.log(e.pageX) //just a placeholder code
    })

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseListener);

    // Specify how to clean up after this effect:
    return function cleanup() {
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseListener);
    };
  });
```